# Accessing functions from a 3rd Party SDK in Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdk, dllimport

I am wanting to work with a specific piece of hardware that I have gotten from a vendor. I found out that they have an sdk. I downloaded the documentation and materials and everything else needed. Included in the file are a .lib and a .dll.

How do I use these files in order to access functions? Can someone give me an example of how to load the dll and access the function? Or can I include the .lib file somehow and allow it to load and coordinate the functions it covers?

**Did everything listed belowe and got this list of compiler errors**
http://pastebin.com/uS24iEKi

Comment: You should also have access to a .h (header) file. Then you can include the .lib file (in linker input page), and make sure the .dll is available in the search path when executing the application.

Comment: Where should the  .dll be relative to everything else?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need also SDK h-file, which should be included in the package you have. To use SDK in VC++ project, follow these steps:

1. Include SDK h-file(s) to your own project files.
2. Add SDK .lib file to the list of project linker depencencies.
3. Ensure that SDK .dll file is available at runtime (placed in current, executable, Windows or System32 directory, or available through PATH).
4. In your code, call SDK functions, or create SDK class instance and call its methods.

Comment: When I try to compile VS is giving a large amount of errors in the SDK supplied headerfile. Such as "  'BYTE' undeclared identifier " and " 'ULONG' : undeclared identifier" .

Comment: I put the header file in the VS/include directory. I also put the dll into system32. I then added the .lib file to the linker input.

Comment: @danes: it looks like you need to include windows.h before including SDK h-file.

Comment: @danes: to compile ULONG and BYTE, you need to include windows.h. Is this done? Also, SDK usually contain code samples - look there to see how to compile your code.

Comment: I added windows.h and winuser.h BEFORE GobiConnectionMgmtAPI.h and this stopped the errors.